# padding is removed on scroll outlook 2016 (windows)

Tags: html, css, outlook

I've run into what I think is a bug with Outlook 2016 (windows 7) that I just can't figure out or get around. Even if I can't fix it, I would like to know if anyone else has run into this issue before.  Every other email client I have tested renders my code perfectly.

When you scroll through the email, the layout changes (see link before, look for the jagged edge on the right). The edge should of course all be flush, with the same padding as the left side.

[layout changes on scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq1KZ.gif)

I have done everything I can think of to prevent this. I have wrapped everything in more tables, change the padding to be on inner table cells, etc.  Has anyone else seen this before?

Comment: sorry but this is not a programming related question.
maybe try on serverfault?

Answer (score 0):

We've all run into padding issues with Outlook.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/padding/
- http://www.informz.com/blog/email-marketing-tips/top-5-tips-for-optimizing-your-email-for-outlook-2016/
- [css padding is not working in outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474239/css-padding-is-not-working-in-outlook)

Without an idea which Outlook client you're talking about, the html code, there's not much we can do to help you with your issue, other than tell you don't use padding.